# DataFrame error: "overloaded method value filter with alternatives"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to create a new data frame by filter out the rows which is null or empty string using the code below:

```
val df1 = df.filter(df("fieldA") != "").cache()
```

Then I got the following error:

```
 <console>:32: error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
      (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
      (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
     cannot be applied to (Boolean)
                  val df1 = df.filter(df("fieldA") != "").cache()
                                 ^
```

Does anyone know what I missed here? Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Scala, in order to compare equality column-wise, you should use `===` and `!==` (or `=!=` in Spark 2.0+):

```
val df1 = df.filter(df("fieldA") !== "").cache()
```

Alternatively, you can use an expression:

```
val df1 = df.filter("fieldA != ''").cache()
```

Your error happened because the `!=` operator is present in every Scala object and it's used to compare objects, always returning Boolean. However, the `filter` function expects a Column object or an expression in a String, so there is the `!==` operator in the `Column` class, which returns another Column and then can be used in the way you want.

To see all operations available for columns, the [Column scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is very useful. Also, there is the [`functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) package.

Comment: I tried using !== but it didn't work (said its deprecated), and suggested to use =!= instead.